# When will the Box v1 api cease to function?

Tags: box-api

I am trying to determine which version of the Box api I should use. My decision hinges on the timeline of EOL of the v1 api. 
I don't want to finish up my app, and just before (or shortly after) the release of the app, the v1 api quits working.

I would gladly use the v2 api, but I am writing a C# app. Since there is a C# SDK for the v1 api, it would be more convenient (in the short-term) to use v1 of the api; but like I said, I'm concerned about the EOL of the v1 api.

Comment: Please consider that [Stack Overflow is not a Crystal Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131257/143302) and [Stack Overflow is not a proxy for customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/143302).

Comment: I realize that Filburt, but there is no information on the Box site concerning this specific issue. The forums at Box point to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We began the process of deprecating the v1 API in December of 2013.  The v2 API was made generally available (GA) a year prior to that, and was in released into Beta in March of 2012.

We have extended our support for all actively used apps built on the v1 API for an additional 3 months, after which v1 API support has been phased out.

The v2 API is now well proven, has about 3x the performance, as well as 10%-20% more surface area that it exposes for use.

Comment: V1 API officially was deprecated December 15th 2013.  Documentation on how to migrate was posted in early 2013, and updated until October of 2013.