# Are there paging mechanisms in the box v2 API?

Tags: paging, box-api

I'm looking at the APIs for things like [retrieve a folder's items](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-retrieve-a-folders-items) and [retrieve the discussion's comments](http://developers.box.com/docs/#dicussions-retrieve-the-discussions-comments) and I don't see any paging mechanisms.

Am I missing something, or is there a reason why they aren't there ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see our convention for paging under the [/user endpoint](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise). We haven't yet implemented this for any other endpoints but will do so before v2 [reaches GA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824276/1154983).