# Does the v2 upload API handle 100-continue?

Tags: box-api

I've recently noticed that when uploading large files, Box doesn't seem to respond with an error until the upload completes. I am setting `Expect: 100-continue` in my request headers, but it seems like the Box servers are ignoring it.

Am I mistaken in this, or is there some way to make the Box servers respect my `Expect: 100-continue` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently support `100-continue`, though it's obvious where this would be extremely helpful for API clients. We're currently focused on [getting the v2 API to GA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824276/1154983), after which point we'll be able to add things like support for `100-continue`.